# ¿Cómo importar datos de una BD de SQL Server a VSC 2019 sin SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Mi PC no quiere instalar *SQL Server* por lo tanto uso el SQL local de Visual Studio, necesito importar unas tablas de una base de datos de SQL Server 2019 llamada *AdventureWorks2019* para poder trabajar con las tablas en el visual, o sea las queries o las tablas de esa base de datos ¿Cómo lo importo al localdb de Visual Studio sin tener SQL instalado?

Comment: si con el localDb te refieres al **SQL Server Express** que se puede instalar como componente del Visual studio,  ya tienes un SQL server instalado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes descargar el backup de BD en [Descargar Backup de AdventureWorks2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms#download-backup-files) e intentar con la siguiente consulta para cargar ese backup.

```
USE [master];
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2019] 
FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2019.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5;
GO
```

**La ruta varía según tu PC y donde lo hayas guardado.**

Comment: ya lo tengo descargado pero no se me refleja en los archivos cuando voy a conectar la base de datos

Comment: ¿Estás intentando cargar el back up desde la consulta o desde la interfaz grafica?

Comment: desde la consulta

Comment: Debes procurar tener el backup en la carpeta de MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup en los archivos del programa